# Ajax call is not going through the withFormat->json on GRAILS controller

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a gsp page that includes a JS function ( named "sample") which does an ajax call.

```
function sample() {
         var params = { office: {id: "testId"}, population: {id: "testId2"}};

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/officeProj/mustache/list",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            complete:function(json){
                console.log(" reponse :"+ json);
            },
            success: function(officeData) {
                var template = "<h1>{{data.firstName}} {{data.lastName}}</h1>";
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                $('#sampleArea').html(html);
            } ,
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("error :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        })

    }
```

Now, this ajax call reaches the appropriate GRAILS controller and appropriate action,defined as:

```
def list = {

    withFormat {
        html { return [title: "Mustache" , data:[firstName:"Indiana", lastName:"Jones"], address:"NYC" ] }
        json {
            // extract the data to be rendered to the page
            println("processing JSON.....")
            render ([title: "Mustache" , data:[firstName:"Indiana", lastName:"Jones"], address:"NYC" ] as JSON)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the control NEVER goes through the withFormat->json in the controller-action and hence I am not seeing the expected result.( When the control comes back to the gsp page, it goes through the the "complete" but not through the "success". No error recorded. Can any one see any problem with my ajax call? Please let me know if I need to provide more information.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually something that gets people, especially when moving from Grails 1.x to Grails 2.x.  You have to read the [docco](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) carefully.

emphasis in bold is mine...

> Another important factor to note is that the withFormat method deals
>   with the **response** format and not the **request** format. As of Grails 2.0,
>   there is a separate withFormat method made available on the request
>   that you can use to handle the request format which is dictated by the
>   CONTENT_TYPE header of the request:

```
request.withFormat {
    xml { .. }
    html { .. }
}
```

Comment: From the doc (http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) "... Renders different responses based on the incoming request Accept header, format parameter or URI extension." And from the ajax call, the *** dataType: "json" *** sets the Accept header to application/json, this is not the request format but the desired response format. Still withFormat doesn't match "json" (tested on grails 2.5.3).

Comment: https://onekilo79.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/angularjs-and-grails-withformat-and-json/ `.get('/book/index.json')`  the trick is to add the .json to the end of the url - the withFormat works fine -  `url: "${createLink(controller: 'someController',action:'someAction.json')}",
    data:{id:${instance.id}},`

Answer (score 4):

Even though, you problem seem to have been solved, i would like to mention the actual reason behind this.

Problem seems to be with the way grails does content negotiation.

according to grails docs, grails will look for the accept header, and that will decide the response format.

But the catch here is, by default, in config.groovy, grails.mime.use.accept.header = false, which basically ignores the accept header, so even though you are setting the dataType:"json" in your ajax request(which will in turn set accept header to "application/json"), it will not look for accept header and response format will always be "all", which is the default.

So basically setting grails.mime.use.accept.header = true, will fix the issue.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution.

The doc says:

> Note that the order of the types is significant **if the request format is "all"** or if more than one content type has the same "q" rating in the accept header. In the former case, **the first type handler in the block is executed**

I take this to mean that if your Accept header looks like this:

`Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`

the `*/*` signifies **accept all** which means the first handler will be used regardless of the rest.

Quick solution: Move the html {} closure to last.

Answer (score 0):

Grails by default ignores accept header for browsers. Read [content negotiation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.4/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation)

> text/xml, application/xml, application/xhtml+xml, text/html;q=0.9, 
>       text/plain;q=0.8, image/png, */*;q=0.5
>
> This particular accept header is unhelpful because it indicates that
>   XML is the preferred response format whereas the user is really
>   expecting HTML. That's why Grails ignores the accept header by default
>   for browsers.

grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents controls which browsers accept header grails will ignore